# Initializing a c++ 11 style singleton

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton

Say I have a singleton class `App` of which I obtain the instance of via:

```
App& App::get()
{
    static App instance;
    return instance;
}
```

From my research, when a singleton is required, this is apparently the best way to obtain it's instance. Suppose however that I need to pass a value once during the initial instantiation such as:

```
void App::init(bool someValue)
{
    static App instance(someValue);
}
```

Where I'm struggling with this concept is how then can I obtain that instance via the `get()` method without having to pass `someValue` every time?

In the past within `init()` I would simply create an `App` instance using the constructor, passing the initialization values and save that instance as a static member to the App class, then `get()` would return that single instance. I seem to be having trouble figuring out how to translate that behavior into this new paradigm. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: In my research, I have never found a case where a singleton is **required**.

Comment: Variable initialisation and construct on first use idiom are incompatible. Choose one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could have a static pointer which points to a local static instance in `init`:

```
// App.hpp
#include <cassert>

class App {
public:
    static void init(bool const b) noexcept {
        static App ap{b};
        _inst = &ap;
    }

    static App& get() noexcept {
        assert(_inst);
        return *_inst;
    }
private:
    App(bool const b)
        : _b{ b }
    {}

    bool _b;
    static App* _inst;
};

// App.cpp

App* App::_inst = nullptr;

// main.cpp

int main() {
    App::init(true);
    auto& ap = App::get(); 
}
```